# Can I use grep to find a file including a particular string?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Can I use grep to find a file including a particular string?
For example, find a file containing "abc" without knowing the file name.

Comment: This question would be better on superuser.com, I think..., but we'll see if gets moved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep -l "abc" *
```

if you want recursive ,

```
grep -R -l "abc" *
```

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
Dir["**/*"].each do |file|
  if test(?f,file)
   open(file).each do |line|
     if line[/abc/]
       puts "line: #{line}"
       puts "file: #{file}"
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`find / -name * | xargs grep -nH abc -` finds all the files that have the string 'abc' and shows the name of the file along with the line number where 'abc' occurs.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Is there a benefit to having `find / -type f` in there, or does `grep` just ignore directories and such anyway?

Comment: I think `grep` silently ignores those that are not regular files, the results don't vary.  May be it speeds up, but for my `find | grep` works are too small to notice the possible speed differences. :)